# Best non-regex way to remove all characters after and including the first non-digit in Python

Tags: python

Assume a string of 5 chars. The title, I think, is clear, but here are some examples:

```
'716-0' --> '716'
'77820' --> '77820'
```

Regex works fine

```
import re
re.findall(r'\d+', '716-0')[0]
```

but how about a good non-regex way?

Comment: "after" would usually imply "not including" but you seem to be including the non-digit character when you remove it.

Comment: What's the problem you're trying to solve? Why not use the regex and spend this time on actual functionality?

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen good catch, thanks, I meant "including", will fix now

Comment: also the regex `r'\d+'` will only "remove all characters after the first non-digit" when the first character **is** a digit, `re.findall(r'\d+', 'a716b')[0]` would give `'716'`.

Comment: @jonrsharpe cause I'm nerd

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen caught me again :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regex is probably the best way to do it, but if for whatever reason you want to avoid it, you can make use of [`str.isdigit()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isdigit) and [`itertools.takewhile()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.takewhile):

```
from itertools import takewhile

string = "716-0"
number = "".join(takewhile(str.isdigit, string))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def trim(x):
    output=[]
    for digit in x:
        if digit in [str(x) for x in range(10)]:
            output.append(digit)
        else:
            break
    return ''.join(output)
```